# UILabel - autoresize

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How is it possible to resize size of text in UILabel in order to fit in the label? (I don't want those 3 dots to appear)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
UILabel *label;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFit = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 5.0; // or whatever else minimum font size you want
```

... should do the trick!

Comment: minimumFontSize is in fact deprecated in iOS 6. Use minimumScaleFactor. (i.e. label.minimumScaleFactor = .3f;

Comment: 1. `[label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];` 2. `[label setMinimumScaleFactor:minimumFontSize / maximumFontSize];`.